# How to use Android Native Language voice output for "Tamil" language

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am creating an android app which has native language voice output and i am going to use Tamil and how to give voice output for this language using ttf.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the language you are looking for?

Comment: there en us,es locale are available by default in android but i need to add hindi, tamil to this locale.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, Tamil locale should be ta_IN. Check it out.